# 404 error when changing store view

Tags: error, store-view, language, 404

I have a site with 4 languages. When i'm at a product and changing to another language i get a 404 error.
Only on the homepage it works well. Any idea to resolve this?

Comment: only the product page issue or else?

Answer (score 1):

Not all products/categories may be visible in all stores, hence, when you change store you are requesting the same url but with the to/from store parameters bolted onto the end.
Depending on how your URLs have been setup you may have different urls for the product anyway.

You can do many things to fix this. First, look at how the store switcher works and whether anyone uses it. Can GeoIP remove the need for anyone ever needing to use it? If so then add GeoIP and don't worry to much about fixing it.

Store codes in URLs can also help with a solution. Are you using store codes?